# Is the code for <canvas> elements in html changed, none of my code seems to be working? I’m trying to draw a line

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, github-pages

I keep encountering errors when trying to draw anything in html  elements. I’ve gone onto reddit, W3 Schools, and about 30 other tutorials. I asked ChatGPT, and it gave me the same code. Nothing is off in the dev console either. Please help.
Here is the link to my github page… https://finnyjokes.github.io/JavascriptGames/

I tried changing variables, even going as far as to remove my css. I was originally using external JS, and am now using in-line JS, which I hate.
Here is the full code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JS GAME</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <style>
      body {
        background:black;
        text-align:center;
        color:white;
      }
      canvas {
        background-color:darkgray;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>JSGAME</h1>
    <canvas id="myCanvas">
      <script src="mainGame.js">
          var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
          var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
          ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
          ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
          ctx.stroke();
      </script>
    </canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

It keeps coming up with the canvas showing, and noting else in the canvas.
I’ve been doing web development for 10ish years, but I still can’t figure this out. Please help.

Comment: for a start, a script tag can not have a `src` attribute AND content. It's been that way for more than 10 years (i.e. forever)

Comment: I’m trying that right now.

Comment: yes, see how it works now in the link

Comment: Thank you! The answer-as always-was right in front of my face.